# How to fix my tooltip that is not working with grid of buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I was reading the bootstrap api for [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips). I built a grid of buttons and I want to be able to have a tooltip show when I do a mouseover of a button.

### Problem

See the picture. This is the normal grid.
[image]

Look at the picture below. Notice how all the buttons got pushed to the right and left side and the tooltip appeared. This is not the desired behavior.
[image]

### Code (see it for yourself in plunker link)

I have a [plunke](http://plnkr.co/edit/3EaI8bdjN5D8CvgogABU?p=preview)r that you can see here the demonstrates the entire problem. Mouse over second row button to see all hell break loose.

The HTML code for the button that I can use tooltip on looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default bin-well bin-col-5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on left"></button>​
```

I have added the following javascript after reading in the boostrap api that there is an issue with btn-group type stuff. I added the following:

```
 $('.btn-group').tooltip({'container':'body', 'placement':'top'});​
```

It creates the exact same issue. Really scratching my head.

### Summary

This doesn't make any sense to me. I thought the entire point of tooltip was to have additional content sit on top of the DOM objects behind it? Not push objects out of the way?

I was wondering if it has to be because of the data-toggle attribute fighting my toggleClass javascript? No way, right? So I tried to use tooltip without having the data-toggle attribution, but I cannot invoke the tooltip without this component.

I have also done a ton of googling and everything I read has indicated that I should not be experiencing this problem and it should be working out of the box.

If anyone with much more experience could help point me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it. I have spent some time on this and I feel like this right [now](http://memecrunch.com/meme/33AE/i-have-no-idea-what-i-m-doing/image.jpg).

### NOTE

I am using IE Explorer to show this behavior. This is important because my clients use IE.

Comment: your plunker does not do this for me

Comment: Minor update. In the api, I just found something that states "When using tooltips on elements within a .btn-group or an .input-group, you'll have to specify the option container: 'body' (documented below) to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is triggered)." Okaaay, buuuut, I don't have btn-group or input-group, but still have that problem. And anyway where the heck is it documented? Argh.

Comment: Actually, your problem doesn't happen in chrome or firefox, but they get different problems. Maybe you should switch to jquery tooltip

Comment: @loli Did you try buttons B2 through B10? Those should be the ones that have the tooltips. The rest will not show this behavior. If your plunker is still not working I'll have to trouble shoot it because it's working for me?

Comment: @loli You have a great point that I should have stated from the beginning. I am using IE for this. I'll try googling jquery tooltip. I'm really disappointed in bootstrap here. Gave your replies some rep.

Comment: I do have btn-group. That's the class for the parent div for the buttons in each row. I think this is the cause of my problem. I am trying to see api docs for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/THgloUwFUDkpv5odRGYv?p=preview

Change your javascript to

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

Comment: Many salutations and bows. You are my hero of the day. I thank you for your comments and for your educational assistance.